# How to copy links from one module to another module using DXL

Tags: ibm-doors

I need to copy both *in links* and/or *out links* from one formal module to another formal module in DOORS using DXL scripting

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to be more readable. Also we don't need the title again in the content of your question. Also adding the relevant "DOORS" tag might point other people familiar with it to your question, so they can help you. 

As your question is pretty short you might also add more information - the more you explain the easier it is for others to help you.

Good luck!

Comment: Did you have a look at the answer to [your other question at SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33687138/i-need-a-dxl-script-to-copy-links-from-one-object-to-another-object-in-a-same-mo/33689008#33689008)? The answer here would basically be the same. The only difference is that the target object `other` must be retrieved from not `current Module`, but your other formal module.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the scripts included in the Doors DXL library.

To do this, go to "Tools/DXL Library/Some example programs that illustrate various DXL features/Example of enhanced copy objects tool"

Then a new window will pop-up and from there you can select different options e.g. which attributes to copy, whether to copy or not links, etc.